# Quick and Easy Deserialization and To Text JSON

Tags: c#, json

So I have a big JSON file with lists and stuff that looks like this: [link](http://pastebin.com/8uGGx6Up)

I have also devised the necessary classes using json2csharp.com.

My problem is, I need to output the whole data into a `textBox`. I just need the text representation of this data.

I can obviously call each member, loop through al the list and manage their textual representation, but is there a quick and dirty way to just output the string? I am using JSON.net.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I know how to do it using .net objeccts as given here:
[www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm](http://%09%20newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm)

I was looking for a one go method.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm

Comment: I know this how to do it calling all the classes and so on and so forth. I am looking for a small, 1 shot way.

Comment: Serialize what though? If you have some main object that has a list of `Neighbour` and a list of `Link` then they will automatically be serialized as well.

Comment: It sounds like you have a text file and you want to display the contents in a text box, yes?

Comment: No, I think OP is asking how to serialize a graph of objects.

Comment: How is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(...)` not a "one shot" way?

Comment: I think you need to specify how you want your `text representation` to look like - give some example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize a graph of objects as long as you have the right data structures. For example, you can see how the `Bar` objects are created as an array of objects:

```
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> names;
    private string name;

    public Foo() {
        this.name = "Name";
        this.names = new List<Bar>() {
            new Bar("a"),
            new Bar("b"),
            new Bar("c")
        };
    }

    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public List<Bar> Names {
        get {
            return this.names;
        }
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public Bar(string name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

var o = new Foo();
Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o));
```

Comment: That's my point, is there an oneshot, automated way to do it? Or simply there isn't one?

Comment: What do you mean? If you serialize `Foo`, `Bar` is also serialized. What more do you want?

Comment: Nada, my mistake. Thanks for the soln.